# When Exporting from sql to Csv -> How I change date format

Tags: c#, sql, date, format, export-to-csv

I made my small project(c# app)`your text`, which export data from sql database into the csv file.
I would like to change date format from | 10.01.2022 to -> 2022.01.10.

Thanks for help.

Regards,

vit

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ExtractApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetCSV();

        }

        private static string GetCSV()
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                return CreateCSV(new SqlCommand("Select * from [reports].[xxx]", cn).ExecuteReader());
                cn.Close();
                
            }

        }

        private static string CreateCSV(IDataReader reader)
        {
            string file = "C:\\SqlToCsv\\Data.csv";
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            string headerLine = "";
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                string[] columns = new string[reader.FieldCount];
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    columns[i] = reader.GetName(i);
                   

                }
                headerLine = string.Join(",", columns);
                lines.Add(headerLine);

            }

            //data
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                reader.GetValues(values);
                lines.Add(string.Join(",", values));
            }

            //file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);

            return file;
            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a datetime type to store these dates in your database?

Comment: It is just a date

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft sql server management 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your column type is `Date`, it will be mapped to a `DateTime` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/date-and-time-data#datetime-data-types-and-parameters)) in C#, so we can use pattern matching to get the `DateTime` and convert it to a `string` with the `.ToString` method:

```cs
object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
reader.GetValues(values);

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
{
    if (values[i] is DateTime dateTimeValue)
    {
        values[i] = dateTimeValue.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
lines.Add(string.Join(",", values));
```

More info:

- [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching)
- [Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)
- [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: I should just add this part of code? Or it is instead of the (for) in my code?

Comment: @FallenDraZy Instead of your current code within your `while (reader.Read())` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can write it in sql syntax;
like if the name of date field is:  created_date

In sql you can change it's format by:

```
`Select DATE_FORMAT(created_date, "%M.%m.%d"), other_fields then your condition `
```

Have a great time...